# Post processing the returned object Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, controller

I was wondering if there's a unified hooking mechanism in Laravel to modify the returned object after the controller has done its magic and return a View or Whatever other object it returned.

For example; I'm currently implementing an API which has a unified ResourceCollection with an extra field for meta information.

But, I'd like to populate that meta field after the Collection has been returned by the Controller.

For example:

```
class AccountController extends ApiController
{
    public function index()
    {
        return new ApiResourceCollection(Account::find(Auth::user()->getKey()));
    }
}
```

The `ApiResourceCollection` class returns a normal JSONResource as laravel implements it, just with some added logic attached to it.

However, I'd like to know if I can still modify or add information to the resource after the controller has run its magic.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use a middleware or an event subscriber to post-process the response.

Comment: How about using the Middleware layer for it?

Comment: Why not add/modify that data inside the controller?

Comment: Well, because it should be applicable to any and all responses, the ApiResourceCollection is one of 3 implementations that return a unified response. Common denominator is the fact that it returns a JsonResponse with an optional meta field which i'd like to populate with event data in case things have happened. 

But i'm going to look at Laravel Echo in the mean time. 

Middleware is before controller actions I figured. I've looked in to it, but the documentation specifically says it runs before the request is processed.